# Trying to call action from cshtml fails with routing error?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, attributes

I'm trying to call an action on a controller in an MVC project from a view and I get the following error:

> This can happen when a controller uses RouteAttribute for routing, but no action on that controller matches the request

I've read some people have removed the attribute routing to get this to work but that seems a bit extreme. Does anyone know where to start with this one?

```
//Calling in view like so
@Html.Action("Edit", new { datablockId = 227 })

//THe controller
[RoutePrefix("CustomData")]
public class CustomDataController : Controller, ICustomDataController
{
    [Route("Edit")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int datablockId)
    {
        return this.PartialView(new CustomDataEditViewModel() { DataRows = Data, DataBlockId = datablockId });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try routing the action to that particular controller explicitly like this:

```
@Html.Action("Edit", "CustomData" ,new { datablockId = 227 })
```

Html action accepts aditional parameters that might fix your routing issue, those parameters are: Html.Action("Action", "Controller", Parameters)